# Converting date time to string with separator "T"

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, converters, date-format

How do I convert a date object with a "T" to separate the date and time

E.g., `2013/07/22T09:43:21` instead of just `2013/07/22 09:43:21`

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Add a `T` in your format string

Comment: A date has no format. So if you have something with a T you have the *representation* of a date, i.e. a string. Parse it into a date and use `ToString` to get the date in a different format. Malvin's link will help you with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ToString` with a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) that contains `T` at the desired position.

```
var date = new DateTime(2013, 07, 22, 09, 43, 21);
var output = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/ddThh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that i've used `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to avoid that `/` gets replaced with your actual culture's date-separator.

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/thylp5) `2013/07/22T09:43:21`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following format string:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/ddTH:mm:ss")
```